# How to make ksh act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (AIX)?

Tags: shell, login, ksh

When I run the `ksh` command it runs as a Non-Login Shell (as expected). What I am trying to achieve is running `ksh` as a Login Shell like it can be done with `bash`.

Just as reference, `bash` can act as if it had been invoked as a login shell by specifying the `-l` option. Here is an extract of the bash man page:

> ```
> BASH(1)                                                       BASH(1)
>
> NAME
>     bash - GNU Bourne-Again SHell
>
> . . .
>
> OPTIONS
>
>      . . .
>
>      -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).
> ```

This is the link for the man page I see in the AIX server:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ksh.htm

There's an option for disabling the processing of the `$HOME/.profile` file (see the quote below), so there has to be a way to use the KornShell as a login shell.

> ```
> ksh Command
>
> Purpose
>     Invokes the Korn shell.
>
> . . .
>
> Flags
>
>      . . .
>
>      -p        
>           Disables the processing of the $HOME/.profile file when you use the shell as a login shell, right?
> ```

### Notes:

The Operating System is AIX and [this is everything I have for `exec`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/exec.htm). Unfortunately, I cannot replace the shell with the following sentence:

```
exec -a ksh path/to/ksh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change your login shell then you can use `chsh` (change shell). If you simply want to run an instance of `ksh` which behaves as a login shell, then read on.

`ksh` behaves as a login shell if the first character of argument 0 is `-`; if you are in `ksh` (`ksh93` or `mksh`, not `ksh88` nor pdksh), `zsh`, `yash` or `bash`, then

```
exec -a -ksh /path/to/ksh [optional arguments]
```

will replace the current shell with an instance of the Korn shell which behaves as a login shell. (If you are in `bash` or `zsh`, then `exec -l /path/to/ksh` is shorter and has the same effect.)

If none of those shells are available, you can also try `perl`:

```
perl -e 'exec {"ksh"} "-ksh"'
```

Comment: Hi @AlexP, thanks for your answer...unfortunately I don't have that `exec` command ( [man page here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/exec.htm) ). Do you know if there is a portable solution for this matter? I will update my question

Comment: By the way @AlexP, in the answer `exec -a -ksh /path/to/ksh [optional arguments]` the `-ksh` should be substituted by `ksh` since that is the name that will be passed for `$0` when exec substitutes the current shell with `/path/to/ksh`  Right? :)

Comment: `exec` is a shell command; the command indicated works in ksh and bash. `ksh` behave as a login shell when `$0` begins with a hyphen.